# Why am I showing up as two contributors in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, smartgit, author

I am using SmartGit 17 and GitLab Enterprise 8.6.0-ee, on Windows 7 Enterprise.  I upgraded SmartGit not too long ago from version 7.1.  I've been working intermittently on a project (I'm the only person working on this project), and today decided to browse around GitLab a little.  I noticed on the Graphs page, Contributors tab, that it shows two contributors, both of whom are me.  One has my full first and last name, and the other has only my last name.  One has my e-mail address all in lower case and the other has it in mixed case.  Over time, there is a ramp-down from May 28 to a little after July 2 of the one contributor, and a corresponding ramp up of the other one.

I vaguely seem to remember being prompted to enter my name and e-mail address and accepting a default (which was just my last name), and I think it is related to SmartGit, but I can't see to find where this is recorded so I can change it back globally rather than on a per-repository basis.

Can anyone tell me where to look?

Also, I don't konw whether "contributor" means committer or author, or if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a contributor is identified via the email address of the user commiting.

As you mentioned vaguely having to enter that information at some point, I reckon it was probably at that point that you ended up with multiple 'identities' within gitlab.

To check what your current email address is configured to and/or modify it you can run the following from a command prompt window (as long as git is on the PATH)

```
git config --global user.email
```

That will display the current globally configured email, to set it:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com
```

More information can be found in the github pages on this [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/).

Comment: You are probably right that that prompt is when I ended up with two GitLab identities.  The question is, where did that second set of identity information come from?  I didn't make it up and enter it, it was a prepopulated pair of fields popped up in SmartGit, with an option (that I declined) to change it.  As it happens, I think I have part of the answer.  It has to do with .gitconfig.  I had two copies of .gitconfig: one in my home directory, and one in my SmartGit 7.1 system directory.  But there was no .gitconfig file in my SmartGit 17 system directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `.gitconfig` file.

If you're using Ubuntu, just do:

```
sudo nano home/<yourUserName>/.gitconfig
```

Then change those 2 lines:

```
[user]
    name = enterYourNameHere
    email = enteryourEmailHere
```

**Don't forget to do the same thing (with the exact user.name and user.email) on each machine you're using!**

> "... One has my e-mail address all in lower case and the other has it
>   in mixed case."

For your information: This bug has been reported by Gitlab team. See [contributor emails in contributors graphs is case sensitive](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19550) and/or [Resolve : contributor emails in contributors graphs is case sensitive](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/8021)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention I'm on Windows 7 - didn't even realize SmartGit is available for other operating systems (also didn't realize just how provincial/parochial I had become in my little Windows world).  But thank you for the links to the gitlab bug and resolution.  That explains the Gitlab side of the issue.

Comment: Why it should be needed to use `sudo` to edit your own files?

Answer (score 0):

In SmartGit you can edit the user name and email address in the Repository | Settings dialog. To update the global config (`~/.gitconfig`) you need to select the "[ ] Remember as default" checkbox.